# FAIL - Application at context path /icescrum could not be started

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to deploy iceScrum in using tomcat. I couldn't start the app in the manager, it is showing the above FAIL message. In ice scrum.log

```
2014-06-24 08:42:26,983 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
        ... 3 more
```

I have no idea what went wrong. I followed all the steps mentioned in https://www.kagilum.com/documentation/install-guide/#application-server. Have anyone come across this kind of issues?

P.S. I am an iOS dev.

Comment: Link asking for login. Please post your config file snippets.

Comment: @vinayknl sorry about that. Are you referring to the config.groovy snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

icescrum dosent support Java 8 yet.

> iceScrum requires Java 6 or 7. Please note that early versions of Java
>   6 may not work properly and that Java 8 support is planned but not
>   available yet.

changing the java version to 7 fixed the issue. And the app runs without any problems.